# Predicate Logic: Distinguishing structures in the first-order language having only multiplication

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I am attempting to distinguish the below structures under the multiplication function. As of right now I have determined the following:

<N, ⋅>*|= ∃z∀x∀y ((x-x=z)∩(y-y=z))  (x*y ≥ z)

- "There exists a z that equals the difference of all x and y with themselves. For all x and y the product is always at least zero"

<Q, ⋅>*|= ∀z (z=(z1/z2)) ∀x∀y(x*y=z) ∀x∃y (z1∤z2)∪(z2∤z1)

- "Every z consists of a numerator and denominator. For all x and y, the product is z. For all x there exists a number where the product consists of a numerator and denominator that do not divide each other without remainder"

<Z, ⋅>*|= ~(∃z∀x∀y ((x-x=z)∩(y-y=z))  (x*y ≥ z)) ∩ ~(∀z (z=(z1/z2)) ∀x∀y(x*y=z) ∀x∃y (z1∤z2)v(z2∤z1))*

- "Not <N, ⋅> and not <Q, ⋅>"

However, I have come to realize that I am not allowed to use other relations, such as less than or equal to, and other functions, such as subtraction.

I understand the concept of the structure statements but lack the imagination to properly distinguish them.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call an element $z$ "unreachable" if the only way to produce $z$ as a product of two elements is for one of the factors to be $z$ itself.

$\mathbb Q$ has exactly one unreachable element, namely $0$.

$\mathbb Z$ has exactly two unreachable elements, namely $0$ and $-1$.

$\mathbb N$ has more than two unreachable elements, namely every prime number, as well as $1$ (and $0$ if $0$ is in your $\mathbb N$).

Comment: How come -1 is unreachable in ℤ but not in ℚ?

Comment: @AlecLeonK: In $\mathbb Q$ we have, for example, $-1=\frac12\cdot (-2)$. But the only way for a product in $\mathbb Z$ to yield $-1$ is $-1=1\cdot(-1)$ or $-1=(-1)\cdot 1$

Comment: I see, this gives a clear cut distinction between the three structures! Is there a way to express these distinctions as statements as I did in my question? For example, would it be possible to express the number of unreachable elements?

Comment: @AlecLeonK: If $\varphi(x)$ is a property, you can express that there are at most one element with the property: $\forall x\forall y(\varphi(x)\land\varphi(y)\to x=y)$, and that there are three different elements with the property: $\exists x\exists y\exists z(x\ne y\land y\ne z\land x\ne z\land \varphi(x)\land\varphi(y)\land\varphi(z))$.

Comment: Oh perfect! So in this case, ℚ⊨∀x∀y(φ(x)∧φ(y)→x=y) and ℕ⊨ ∃x∃y∃z(x≠y∧y≠z∧x≠z∧φ(x)∧φ(y)∧φ(z)) and ℤ would be neither of those? Also I defined φ(z) := x*y=z ^ x=z

Comment: @AlecLeonK: The intention was that $\varphi(z)$ should be a formula with $z$ as its only free variable, which intuitively encodes "$z$ is unreachable".

Answer (score 2):

First, you can define $1$ by saying $ \varphi(x) \equiv \forall y (x \cdot y = y)$.

Now you know that $\mathbb{Q} \models \forall x \exists y (x \cdot y =1)$ and $\mathbb{N} \models \neg \forall x \exists y (x \cdot y =1)$. So putting the two above together, we note that

$$\mathbb{Q} \models \forall x \exists y (x \cdot y =1) \equiv (\exists z)[\varphi(z) \wedge  \forall x \exists y (x \cdot y = z )] $$

$$\mathbb{N} \models \neg \forall x \exists y (x \cdot y =1) \equiv \neg (\exists z)[\varphi(z) \wedge  \forall x \exists y (x \cdot y = z )] $$

Comment: Perfect, I understand that! Since you compared the rational numbers to the natural numbers I am a bit confused on how to distinguish the integers now because integers would agree with the natural numbers.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, I had something like that on the tip of my tongue. So would it make sense to write ℤ⊨∃x∃y∃z((x^2=z) ∧ (y^2=z))?

Comment: @AlecLeonK: Yes, more or less, except that you're missing a condition that $z\ne y$. And, of course, $\mathbb Q$ satisfies this too.